# Were any other members of the Kennedy (Political) family affected by Addison's disease?

Tags: united-states, political-history, president

Besides JFK, are there any known Addison's sufferers in the [Kennedy political family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_family)?

Comment: Is there some reason to think that they would have been? Addison’s disease isn't genetic.

Comment: This is a "answer if you have valid input" question. Seriously, Samuel Clemens quotes apply here.

Comment: My government seems to think otherwise: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3484749, http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Addisons-disease/Pages/Causes.aspx

Comment: @Cbaker510: That's a 31 year old paper now - written long before the human genome was sequenced. Do you have any reference more recent?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any known Addison's sufferers in the Kennedy political family?

Yes.  His younger sister, [Eunice Mary Kennedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eunice_Kennedy_Shriver).

---

[JFK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy#Health) was formally diagnosed as having Addison's disease in September 1947, aged 30.  He also suffered from hypothyroidism.  His Wikipedia page notes that:

> The presence of two endocrine diseases raises the possibility that Kennedy had [autoimmune polyendocrine syndrome type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoimmune_polyendocrine_syndrome_type_2) (APS 2).

---

About half of the people who suffer with APS-2 also have relatives who are affected by an autoimmune disease. [source: Barbara A. Majeroni & Parag Patel: [Autoimmune Polyglandular Syndrome, Type II](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2007/0301/p667.html), Am Fam Physician, 2007].

Although the inheritance pattern in APS-2 appears to be determined by multiple genes, given that link, it is perhaps unsurprising that a 2009 review of Kennedy's case stated:

> It is public knowledge that **Kennedy's younger sister, Eunice, had Addison disease** and that his son, John F. Kennedy, Jr., had Graves disease.

- [Lee R. Mandel: [Endocrine and Autoimmune Aspects of the Health History of John F. Kennedy](https://annals.org/aim/fullarticle/744707/endocrine-autoimmune-aspects-health-history-john-f-kennedy?searchresult=1), Annals of Internal Medicine, 1 September 2009] (my emphasis)

---

If you are interested, the story of, and background to, JFK's diagnosis with Addison's disease is covered in Joan & Clay Blair's book, [The search for JFK](https://archive.org/details/searchforjfk00joan/page/560), pp 560-